# Java class testing issues

Tags: java, netbeans

Hello I have a problem testing this, as I get an error that the testing is not right, can you guys explain why and what are the mistakes?

```
public void addDays(int x) {
    int y = year;
    day = day + x;     
    if (day > 31) {     
      day = day - 31;   
      addMonths(1); 

    } else if (day >= 29 && month == 2 && (isLeapYear(y))) {
      day = day - 29;
      addMonths(1);
    } else if (day >= 28 && month == 2 && !(isLeapYear(y))) {
      {
        day = day - 28;
        addMonths(1);

      }
    }
  }
```

and this is my test for this method (Im using Netbeans).

```
     @Test
   public void testAddDays() {
    Date z = new Date(31,11,2013);
    z.addDays(3);
 assertEquals(3, z.getDay());

}  
           @Test
   public void testAddDays1() {
    Date z = new Date(28,2,2016);
    z.addDays(3);
 assertEquals(2, z.getDay());
}  
              @Test
   public void testAddDays2() {
    Date z = new Date(29,2,2014);
    z.addDays(2);
 assertEquals(3, z.getDay());
}
```

I would like to know where are my mistakes and how can I fix them

Comment: Stop using the snippet functionality; it's meant strictly for **client-side** code snippets (html, javascript) **only**

Comment: What about the months that have exactly 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to replace your custom-built date arithmetic with the `java.util` classes [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), unless there's a reason *not* to use them (such as this being a date calculation exercise), since those utility classes are standard and well-tested.

For consistency with the `Calendar` class, I'd recommend a (year, month, date) format instead of your (date, month, year). That will make it more convenient to test your code against `java.util` results.

---

So, to look at your test cases, using your `Date(date, month, year)` format, on the assumption that you're not allowed to use `java.util`:

- testAddDays: This adds three days to Date(31, 11, 2013). Since 2013-11-31 is not a well-formed date, the constructor should change it to 2013-12-01. Adding three days is 2013-12-04, so getDay() should return 4.
- testAddDays1: This adds three days to Date(28, 2, 2016), a leap year. The next three days are 2016-02-29, 2016-03-01, and 2016-03-02, so getDay() should return 2.
- testAddDays2: This adds two days to Date(29, 2, 2014), a common year. Since 2014-02-29 is not a well-formed date, the constructor should change it to 2014-03-01. Adding two days is 2014-03-03, so getDay() should return 3.

One obvious bug in your `addDays(int x)` method is that it doesn't test for `x` greater than one month. If you're not worried that the code will be slow for large `x`, you could iterate through all the months with something like this:

```
if (x < 0) {
  subtractDays(x);
  return;
}
day += x;
while (day > 0) {
  int daysThisMonth;
  switch (month) {
    case 2: daysThisMonth = isLeapYear() ? 29 : 28; break;
    case 4: case 6: case 9: case 11: daysThisMonth = 30; break;
    case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12: daysThisMonth = 31; break;
    default: // ERROR.
  }
  addMonths(1);
  day -= daysThisMonth;
}
```

Note that this code depends on `addMonths()` ignoring `day`, which is a code maintenance problem. I'm assuming there's also a `subtractDays()` method; if not, you'll need to revise your `addDays()` to allow for negative `x`.

There may also be problems in your constructor; it needs to test for handle dates that do not conform with calendar standards.